# What is the difference between setValue(name) and setValue(...name) in useState?

Tags: reactjs

which is the correct way in updating a state which is an array, setValue(name) or setValue(...name)? What is the use of spread operator(...)? Through me some insights about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a next code and you will understand this:
We have:

```
const [names, setNames] = useState(null);
```

Let's imagine that you do add name and now you do this:

```
setNames(['Andrii']);
```

You will see that your state was updated and your list of names have one value 'Andrii'

if you want to add new name then you need do next;

```
setNames([...names].concat('Vlad'));
```

if you do this:

```
names.push('Vlad');
setNames(names)
```

then you will not see result because setState will update your page only if state has new value.
You don't have a new value because objects has links and it works like this:

oldState === newState ? 'do nothing' : 'update'

[...names] it is a new array

names.push('something')
names != new array because it's old array with a new value